# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\AdminTampilSekolahController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do a basic CRUD app, but this is what I got.

Can it be because the variable `$sekolah` can't read?

**this is the source code**

*web.php*

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

// Route::get('/event', function () {
//  $namaevent = 'contoh event';
//     return view('event',['namaevent' => $namaevent]);

//route CRUD
Route::get('/tampilsekolah','AdminTampilSekolahController@index');

Route::get('/event','EventController@index');

Route::get('/loker','LokerController@index');

Route::get('/pencarian', function () {
    return view('pencarian');
});

Route::get('/listsekolah', function () {
    return view('listsekolah');
});

Route::get('/sekolaah', function () {
    return view('test');
});
```

*AdminTampilSekolahController.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers;

class InputSekolahController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // mengambil data dari table tb_sekolah
        $sekolah = DB::table('tb_sekolah')->get();

        // mengirim data sekolah ke view inputsekolah
        return view('admintampilsekolah',['sekolah' => $sekolah]);

    } 
}
```

and the view *admintampilsekolah.blade.php*

```
<!doctype html>
<html >
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">

    <title>List Sekolah (ADMIN)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<!-- isi web  -->
  <div class="countainer">
    <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 85%; margin-top: 5%;">
      <div class="card-header">
                ...........
            </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">.........</h5>
          <div class="table-responsive-xl">
            <table class="table table-bordered tabel table-striped">
                    <thead class="thead-dark text-center">
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Kode Sekolah</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nama</th>
                        <th scope="col">Jenjang</th>
                        <th scope="col">Alamat</th>
                        <th scope="col">Kecamatan</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Notelp</th>
                        <th scope="col">Jumlah Guru</th>
                        <th scope="col">Jumlah Murid</th>
                        <th scope="col">Prestasi</th>
                        <th scope="col">Sarana</th>
                        <th scope="col">Akreditasi</th>
                        <th scope="col">Kurikulum</th>
                        <th width="10%" scope="col" colspan="2" >Option</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="text-center">
                    @foreach($sekolah as $s)
                            <tr>
                            <td>{{$s->Kode}}></td>
                            <td>{{$s->Nama}}></td>
                            <td>{{$s->Jenjang}}></td>
                            <td>{{$s->Alamat}}></td>
                            <td>{{$s->Kecamatan}}></td>
                            <td>{{$s->Email}}></td>
                            <td>{{$s->Notelp}}></td>
                            <td>{{$s->Jumlahguru}}></td>
                            <td>{{$s->Jumlahmurid}}></td>
                            <td>{{$s->Prestasi}}></td>
                            <td>{{$s->Sarana}}></td>
                            <td>{{$s->Akreditasi}}></td>
                            <td>{{$s->Kurikulum}}></td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/tb_sekolah/edit/{{$s->Kode}}" class="btn btn-primary ">EDIT</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>    
                                <a href="/tb_sekolah/hapus/{{$s->Kode}}" class="btn btn-danger ">DELETE</a>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                    </table>        
          </div>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the class in the controller should follow the name of the file

Change

```php
class InputSekolahController extends Controller
```

To

```php
class AdminTampilSekolahController extends Controller
```

Because Laravel uses composer and reflection to build a class-map

You may need to run

```
composer dumpautoload
```

After this so that the class loads

Comment: yeah, it was my fault to change the name file without change the class name. thanks it works perfectly now